# can I set multiple JavaScript files on a custom module library?

Tags: 8, javascript

I created a new module and I need to add multiple JavaScript files to my pageI.

Should I create a new library for each file, or is it possible to add multiple JavaScript files on the same library as in the following library definition?

```yaml
organigram_admin_library:
  version: 1.0
  js:
    js/admin/jquery-1.10.2.min.js: {}
    js/admin/admin.js: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add multiple JS and CSS files to the same library.
Here is an example you can follow.

```
custom-jbox-modal:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/StephanWagner/jBox@v1.3.2/dist/jBox.all.min.css': {type: external, minified: true}
  js:
    '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/StephanWagner/jBox@v1.3.2/dist/jBox.all.min.js': {type: external, minified: true}
    js/jbox-custom-modal.js: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal doesn't put any limit on the number of JavaScript files a library can contain. This is how the *drupal.collapse* library is defined in [core.libraries.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.libraries.yml/8.9.x).

```yml
drupal.collapse:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    misc/details-aria.js: {}
    misc/collapse.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/modernizr
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupal.form
    - core/jquery.once
```

It's not a common case in Drupal core, as most of the libraries contain a single JavaScript file, and adds the other files as dependencies, but that doesn't mean a library cannot contain more than a JavaScript file.

In the case of using a jQuery file different from the one used from Drupal core, I would be careful, and first verify it doesn't create issues.